# SQL select statement with column being null sometimes

Tags: sql, excel, stored-procedures, vba

I am wondering how I would go about creating an SQL select statement that may have a possible null in a couple of the columns. Here is what one possible result set could look like:

```
Volume    |  Ticket   |  Hours   |  Rate   |   Amount
              1234        10.5       190        1995
  90                      90         100        9000
              1235        11         190        2090
  90                      90         110        9900
```

the volume is related the their above ticket. So the first time a ticket is display we don't want to show the volume, but we want to show the Ticket #. If there is Volume we want the next line to display it's values, but not the ticket.

The table table that I am pulling from is `Charges`. These are the columns:

`ChargeID, TicketNum, ProductID, Hours, Rate, Amount`

Where ChargeID is a primary key.

If anyone has as any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ChaseErsnt, do you have primary key on that table?

Comment: How do you know which volume goes with which ticket?

Comment: Certain products can be labeled Fluid inside the Products table. @tvelykyy updated question

Comment: @ChaseErnst it would be easier to help you if you provide complete schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (This is in Oracle, though .. )
Not sure why you have this question flagged vba ..

```
  with w_data as ( 
           select 33 volume, 1234 ticket, 10.5 hours, 190 rate, 1995 amount from dual union all
           select 90 volume, 1234 ticket, 90   hours, 100 rate, 9000 amount from dual union all
           select 33 volume, 1235 ticket, 11   hours, 190 rate, 2090 amount from dual union all
           select 90 volume, 1235 ticket, 90   hours, 110 rate, 9900 amount from dual 
        )
  Select case when ticket = lag(ticket) over (partition by ticket order by ticket, volume) then volume else null end new_volume, 
        case when ticket = lag(ticket) over (partition by ticket order by ticket, volume) then null else ticket end new_ticket, 
           hours, rate, amount
    from w_data
  order by ticket, volume
  /

  NEW_VOLUME NEW_TICKET      HOURS       RATE     AMOUNT
  ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
                   1234       10.5        190       1995
          90                    90        100       9000
                   1235         11        190       2090
          90                    90        110       9900

  4 rows selected.
```

Comment: I will try to convert this to sql and give this a try.